# Extract an area which is drawn by black line

Tags: matlab, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

I want to extract area which is drawn by black line.

[image]

Any idea please?

Comment: please provide more than a thumbnail. also what are your ideas? we help you solve problems. we don't solve them for you

Comment: I hope you know a good surgeon, looks like a big section to extract

Answer (score 0):

use [polyarea()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyarea.html) function.

> a = polyarea(x,y) returns the area of the 2-D polygon defined by the
>   vertices in vectors x and y.